# Suppose f : $\mathbb R → \mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $x ≤ f(x) ≤ x+1$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb R$. Find $f(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f : $\mathbb R → \mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $x ≤ f(x) ≤ x+1$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb R$. Find $f(\mathbb R)$.

I dont know how to start with this problem..

Comment: Note that $y=x$ and $y=x+1$ is a pair of parallel lines for which $f(x)$ is bounded by.

Comment: I know that the function gonna be between x and x +1 that are parallel lines.

Comment: If the solution depends *only* on the assumptions of $f$, then it must be $\mathbb{R}$ because $f(x)=x$ obviously satisfies the assumptions. OK, one might say that this is "cheating". Where is this exercise from?

Comment: this exercise form Basic Analysis By: Jiří Lebl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No $x\in \mathbb R$ is an upper bound for $f(\mathbb R)$  because $x+1\leq f(x+1).$

No $x\in \mathbb R$ is a lower bound for $f(\mathbb R)$ because $f(x-2)\leq x-1<x.$

$f$ is continuous so it has the Intermediate  Value  Property.

Answer (score 0):

$$x ≤ f(x) ≤ x+1$$
But $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto x+1$ tend to $\pm\infty$ when $x$ tends to $\pm\infty$.
So with squeeze theorem $f$ tend to $\pm\infty$ when $x$ tends to $\pm\infty$. Furthermore $f$ is continuous. So by the intermediate value property $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$.